# xml to php conversion

Tags: php, xml, file

I'm trying to print the response from the xml result.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response op="sendsmsmsg" status="400" message="Customer with mobile number 6193030168 is not opted in" version="1.0"/>
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [op] => sendsmsmsg
            [status] => 400
            [message] => Customer with mobile number 6193030168 is not opted in
            [version] => 1.0
        )

)
```

how to echo the op value, status, message to this result into php

Comment: Read the comments; http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the XML is malformed. This one works. **TESTED**

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<response2>
 <op>sendsmsmsg</op>
  <status>400</status>
   <message>Customer with mobile number 6193030168 is not opted in</message>
</response2>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
echo $xml->op."<br>".$xml->status."<br>".$xml->message;
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

> sendsmsmsg
>   400
>   Customer with mobile number 6193030168 is not opted in

Answer (score 0):

i have tested it with your xml :

```
//data.xml has 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response op="sendsmsmsg" status="400" message="Customer with mobile number 6193030168 is not opted in" version="1.0"/>


<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
print($xml['op']);
?>
```